# Opening shapefile with sf in r gives an error

Tags: r, shapefile, r-sf

I want to open a Shapefile in RStudio that is stored on my Mac. I have used the `sf` library and used the following code:

`shapeFile= st_read("/Users/roelalex/Desktop/testFolder/cb_2015_us_county_5m.shp")`

But then I get this error message:

**Error: Cannot open "/Users/roelalex/Desktop/testFolder/cb_2015_us_county_5m.shp"; The source could be corrupt or not supported. See `st_drivers()` for a list of supported formats.
In addition: Warning message:
In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  :
GDAL Error 4: Unable to open /Users/roelalex/Desktop/testFolder/cb_2015_us_county_5m.shx or /Users/roelalex/Desktop/testFolder/cb_2015_us_county_5m.SHX. Set SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX config option to YES to restore or create it.**

Can someone help me with this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're using the US Census Bureau Cartographic Boundary shapefile found [here](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/2015-cartographic-boundary-file-state-county-for-united-states-1-5000000/resource/4fb06884-4fab-4c00-aa1d-ec404bf1f4a5).

Make sure you have the shapefile index (`cb_2015_us_county_5m.shx`) in the same directory as your .shp file. Download it from the above link if you're missing it.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I was stuck for hours! It might make sense for more experienced users but since only the .shp file is called in `st_read()` I didn't think about including the other files in the folder. Thanks again!